# Can a model trained using a GPU be used for inference on a CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to run inference on the CPU; although my machine has a GPU.
I wonder if it's possible to force TensorFlow to use the CPU rather than the GPU?

By default, TensorFlow will automatically use GPU for inference, but since my GPU is not good (OOM'ed), I wonder if there's a setting to force Tensorflow to use the CPU for inference?

For inference, I used:

```
tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model("PATH")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using TensorFlow 2.0, please check out this issue on GitHub:

- [[TF 2.0] How to globally force CPU?](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31135)

The solution seems to be to hide the GPU devices from TensorFlow. You can do that using one of the methodologies described below:

**TensorFlow 2.0:**

```py
my_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type='CPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(devices= my_devices, device_type='CPU')
```

**TensorFlow 2.1:**

```py
tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')
```

(Credit to @ymodak and @henrysky, who answered the question on the GitHub issue.)

Comment: actually i just want to do that in part of the graph rather than globally? wondering if there is a way.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm that case, it might be best to post that as another question on StackOverflow as, I believe, I've answered the question you originally asked here.